# Oracle update duplicate rows in a table

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table called users, with columns

```
name, location, organization, valid_from, valid_to, active.
```

What I am trying to do is: 
if there are two records with same name, location, organization but with valid_to, valid_from intervals overlapping, to set the active status of each record to 'NOK'.
Here's how I am trying to do it :

```
UPDATE table SET active= 'NOK' 
WHERE 
(name, location, organization) IN (
     SELECT t1.name, t1.location, t1.organization   
     FROM table t1
     WHERE (valid_from > t1.valid_from and valid_to < t1.valid_to )
      GROUP BY t1.name, t1.location, t1.organization   
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) ;
```

But this doesn't seem to do what I desire. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WHERE clause in your subquery will be FALSE for all rows because you didn't specify a table alias for some columns:

```
(valid_from > t1.valid_from and valid_to < t1.valid_to )
```

will be assumed to mean

```
(t1.valid_from > t1.valid_from and t1.valid_to < t1.valid_to )
```

I think this does what you want:

```
UPDATE table t1 SET active = 'NOK' 
WHERE EXISTS 
( SELECT 1
  FROM   table t2
  WHERE  t2.name = t1.name
  AND    t2.location = t1.location
  AND    t2.organization = t1.organization
  AND    t1.valid_from <= t2.valid_to
  AND    t2.valid_from <= t1.valid_to
  AND    t1.ROWID != t2.ROWID
);
```

However, if valid_from or valid_to can be null then you need to handle that case also.

(The ROWID comparison is to prevent tows matching with themselves!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
UPDATE table SET a.active= 'NOK' 
from table a
inner join (
     SELECT t1.name, t1.location, t1.organization   
     FROM table t1
     WHERE (valid_from > t1.valid_from and valid_to < t1.valid_to )
      GROUP BY t1.name, t1.location, t1.organization   
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b
  on a.name = b.name and a.location = b.location and a.organization = b.organization;
```